# Prove that a Fermat Number cannot be a Carmichael Number?

Tags: number-theory

Prove that a Fermat Number cannot be a Carmichael number:

Fermat numbers are of the form $2^{2^n}+1$ and $F$($n$) denotes the $n$th Fermat number. If $F$($n$) is a Carmichael number, that would mean for every integer $a$, there would exist an integer $x$ such that $x^2$ $\equiv$ $a$$\pmod n$, in other words, every integer $a$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod n$ where $n$ = $F$($n$). I cannot see why that would be the case for any integer $y$ such that all intgers are quadratic residues $\pmod y$. Would that be a sufficient proof?

Comment: How did you conclude that every integer $a$ has a square root mod $n$?  This doesn't seem to follow at all from the definition of Carmichael number.  What definition are you using?

Comment: The fact that if there did exist a Fermat Number $n$ that is a Carmichael Number as well, then $a^{n-1}$ = $1$ $\pmod n$ for all integers $a$ relatively prime to $n$. However, $a^{(n-1)/2}$ = $1$ $\pmod n$ must also be true because if that wasn't the case, then that would mean n is prime (Lucas Primality Test: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_primality_test) and a Carmichael is composite.

Comment: Ah, that is a very nice observation!  But I'm not convinced that this makes $a$ a quadratic residue, since we don't have Euler's criterion as $n$ is prime (and Euler's criterion uses the existence of primitive roots in an essential way).  For instance, $2^{280} \equiv 1 \pmod {561}$ but there are no solutions to $x^2\equiv 2 \pmod {561}$.

Comment: Better example: the Carmichael number $n=1729$ satisfies $a^{(n-1)/2} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ for all coprime $a$.  Yet this doesn't create any immediate contradiction (and only 12.5% of reduced residues $a$ are quadratic residues).

Comment: Either $a^{(n-1)/2}$ = $1$ $\mod 561$ , Either $a^{(n-1)/5}$ = $1$ $\mod 561$, or Either $a^{(n-1)/7}$ = $1$ $\mod 561$ for all $a$ relatively prime to $561$ since $560$ = $2^4*5*7$. Otherwise that would mean 561 is prime if those conditions did not hold. So Fermat numbers that  are Carmichael Numbers, $a^{(n-1)/2}$ = $1$ $\pmod n$ must be true for all $a$ relatively prime to Fermat Number $n$. However, the examples you gave depend on the factors of $y-1$ where $y$ is a Carmichael Number based on the Lucas Primalty Test.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my point.  I completely agree that $a^{(n-1)/2} \equiv 1$, but this has **nothing** to do with $a$ being a quadratic residue.  $a$ can fail to have a square root and still satisfy $a^{(n-1)/2} \equiv 1$.  I've already given one example for $n=561$ and most values of $a$ for $n=1729$ are examples.  I don't see how you conclude that $a\equiv x^2$ for some $x$.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to consider a prime $p \mid n$: since $n$ is Carmichael, we have $p-1 \mid n-1$ (Korselt’s criterion).  Since $n-1$ is a power of $2$, then also $p-1$ is a power of $2$.  By a standard elementary argument, any odd prime of the form $2^k+1$ must be a Fermat prime.  But one can easily show that no two distinct Fermat numbers can divide one another, so $p$ can't divide $n$ as was assumed.